# How do I make a translucent/transparent material on eevee?

Tags: materials

something like this [image]

ive followed multiple tutorials but they all result in my objects looking shiny, any help?

Comment: show us your settings like material settings via screenshot. or provide your blend file.

Comment: Shiny as in not transparent and pseudo-reflective?

Answer (score 0):

> ive followed multiple tutorials but they all result in my objects looking shiny, any help?

So your question is actually how to make a material not shiny.

If you have looked up tutorials, you probably have found already so I will make it simple and pretend you use a principled shader from which you obtain the transparency effect by playing with its transmission and/or alpha settings.

The first obvious sources of any shininess in a material are the specular and metallic settings. They are the ones that make the surface reflect light, so turning them off if the first step.

The second source can be the transmission itself. As transmission is emulating physical light transmission, it refracts light, meaning the light rays going through are deflected at each environment change, which can make you see stuff in a "weird" way, as when looking through a glass or a filled cup of water.
You can tweak that by playing with the Roughness and Transmission Roughness, though if you want no refraction at all you should just turn Transmission off and use the Alpha only; thus making your material not following the laws of physics, but you need what you need anyway.